# Item is not taking up the full height of its parent container

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using react, css, and tailwind to build this web page. A side bar for navigation isnt taking up the full height of its parent container. I have proven the size of the parent and confirmed this is the case. Often times, the second div of my app exceeds the viewport height thus I have set minimum height to 100vh and height to 100% on both.

```
<---------------Side bar CSS class ------------------>
.custom-sidebar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100% !important;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 10%;
    background: #0973FC;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
}

.sidebar-option{
    @apply lg:bg-transparent google-text font-normal text-base bg-blue-800 p-3 drop-shadow rounded-    md items-center text-white stroke-white hover:text-yellow-600 hover:stroke-yellow-600 h-full;
}

<---------END---------->



<----------App component----------->

function App() {

    return (
        <div className='flex flex-row items-stretch min-h-screen h-full border border-red-500'>                               <SideBar/>
            <div className='flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen h-full'>
              //the rest of my routes

<----------END----------->



<----------Side bar component----------->
const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className='custom-sidebar'>
    //the rest of my program

<-----------END------------>
```